# EasyAutocomplete events - $(this) is always undefined

Tags: jquery

I try to use [EasyAutocomplete](http://easyautocomplete.com/) on several elements simultaneously
but `$(this)` always undefined, why?

```
$("#city_selector_suggest, $city_two, #city_down").easyAutocomplete({
    url: "/templates/rm/js/ecity2.json",

    getValue: function(element) {
        return element.cdek_cityname;
    },

    list: {
        onChooseEvent: function() {
            var selectedItemValue = $(this).getSelectedItemData().cdek_id;
            console.log(selectedItemValue);
        },
        match: {
            enabled: true,

            method:  function(element, phrase) {
                if(element.indexOf(phrase) === 0) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: my guess is they do not bind the events to the element... `console.log(this)` is probably showing window. Do the arguments give you anything?

Comment: i can see there is no this in whole code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick test shows that in EasyAutocomplete event handlers, the `this` is used unconventionally, i.e. "not like jQuery does it".

What I would expect from a jQuery plugin:

- `this` inside an event handler points to a DOM element
- the event handler gets at least one `event` argument and possibly an additional `data` argument.

What EasyAutocomplete does:

- `this` is some sort of configuration object of the widget
- there are no arguments for the event handler

The configuration object does not seem to provide any way of getting the widget or even the DOM element the widget is based on.

The closest thing to a solution for that would to use `.each()` and bind the widgets individually, storing a reference to the current element.

```
$("#city_selector_suggest, #city_two, #city_down").each(function () {
    var $self = $(this);

    $self.easyAutocomplete({
        url: "/templates/rm/js/ecity2.json",
        getValue: function(element) {
            return element.cdek_cityname;
        },
        list: {
            onChooseEvent: function() {
                var selectedItemValue = $self.getSelectedItemData().cdek_id;
                console.log(selectedItemValue);
            },
            match: {
                enabled: true,
                method: function(element, phrase) {
                    return element.indexOf(phrase) === 0;
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Not quite as elegant as calling `.easyAutocomplete()` only once—but not completely horrible, either.